# Parse JSON date with GSON

Tags: android, json, gson

How can I parse JSON dates with GSON? Keeps getting errors.

The date format in the JSON looks like this:

```
/Date(1313613992133+0200)\
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Your date-string seams invalid (because of the `+`). Can you post a full JSON-example and tell where you get it from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
    Date date = new Date(Integer.parseInt(jsonDateString.substr(6)));
```

Similar question answered here: [How do I format a Microsoft JSON date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-json-date/2316066#2316066)

Comment: Yes. That will probably work, but can I do this with the GSON parser?

Comment: The String-method is called `substring()`, it differs from the JavaScript string. Also, the String can't be parsed since the `Integer.parseInt()`-method does not ignore the `)\` at the end. Also, in the string provided by the OP, there is a `+` which also causes the method to not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
new Date(Long.parseLong("1313613992133")).toGMTString()
```